# React Site wont render as soon as button is added around <img/>

Tags: reactjs, image-gallery

I am trying to make a dynamic and good looking picture gallery but i am having a problem. Since i want the images to be clickable (so i can expand them) i need to wrap a button around the images. For some reason this is crashing react. I tried around 5 different ways of implementing the button. Sadly none worked

My Code currently looks like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import "./styles/gallery.css"
import Masonry, {ResponsiveMasonry} from 'react-responsive-masonry';
function Gallery() {
  const [pictures, setPictures] = useState([]);
  const [popup, togglepopup] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const importPictures = async () => {
      const context = require.context('../pictures/gallery', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/);
      const files = context.keys();
      const pictures = await Promise.all(files.map(async (file) => {
        const image = await import(`../pictures/gallery/${file.slice(2)}`);
        return {
          src: image.default,
          alt: file.slice(2, -4),
        };
      }));
      setPictures(pictures);
    };
    importPictures();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="galleryElements">
    <ResponsiveMasonry columnsCountBreakPoints={{300: 1, 750: 2, 900: 3, 1400: 4, 1900: 5, 2100: 6}}>
      <Masonry gutter='1rem'>
      
      {pictures.map((picture) => (
        <button className='elementButton' type="button" onClick={togglepopup(!popup)}>
        <img className="element" src={picture.src} alt={picture.alt} key={picture.alt} />
        </button>
      ))}
      
      </Masonry>
    </ResponsiveMasonry>
    
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default Gallery;
```

If i remove the button everything works and is rendered correctly. If it is in there only the background color is rendered. Nothing else. No Navbar, no Footer etc.
If you know any other way of making the popout feature possible i would be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onClick` in your `<img/>` you don't really need `<button>` to do that :

```js
<img 
 className="element"
 src={picture.src} 
 alt={picture.alt} 
 key={picture.alt}
 onClick={() => {
   togglepopup(!popup)
 }}
 />
```

Comment: Hey, sadly that doesnt work. I tried it with a console log and the onClick function is pressed n amount of times (n is the amount of pictures) and then not at all when i click the picture

Comment: did you use the arrow function as mentioned in the answer ? you are probably using it the wrog way ! `onClick={togglepopup(!popup)}` will make the function called on component render

Comment: Yeah i did, i actually found the anwser now. I had Github Copilot activated and i always wrote some bs on in the file for some reason. After i deactivated it, it worked again. Really weird